# proper place to use location api in android mvvm architecture

Tags: android, android-mvvm

I have a scenario, I want to show user current weather data for that I am getting his/her current lat/lng and reverse geocoding it to get the city name. Once I have the city name I will make a network call and show the weather data. Apart from this, there are many location operations I need to perform.

So I have created a class named as `LocationUtils.kt`. I am following MVVM architecture and want to know which is the ideal layer to call the `LocationUtils` methods, is it the `view` layer or the `viewmodel` layer or the `data` layer. Since `FusedLocationProvider` needs `context` and if I use it in `ViewModel` it will leak. So how to solve this problem?

`LocationUtils.kt`:

```
class LocationUtils {
  private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

  private fun isLocationEnabled(weakContext: Context?): Boolean {
    return when {
      Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P -> {
        // This is new method provided in API 28
        val locationManager = weakContext?.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        locationManager.isLocationEnabled
      }
      Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT -> {
        // This is Deprecated in API 28
        val mode = Settings.Secure.getInt(
            weakContext?.contentResolver, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE,
            Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF
        )
        mode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF

      }
      else -> {
        val locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(weakContext?.contentResolver, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED)
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(locationProviders)
      }
    }
  }

  @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
  fun getCurrentLocation(
    weakContext: WeakReference<Context>,
    success: (String?) -> Unit,
    error: () -> Unit
  ) {
    if (isLocationEnabled(weakContext.get())) {
      weakContext.get()
          ?.let { context ->
            fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
            fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location ->
              getCurrentCity(context, location, success)
            }
          }
    } else {
      error()
    }
  }

  private fun getCurrentCity(
    context: Context,
    location: Location?,
    success: (String?) -> Unit
  ) {
    val city = try {
      location?.let {
        val geocoder = Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault())
        val address = geocoder.getFromLocation(it.latitude, it.longitude, 1)
        address[0].locality
      }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      "Bangalore"
    }
    success(city)
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you find anything? I have a similar problem.

Comment: As of now, I am using this in my Activity. But still looking for a recommended solution.

Answer (score 3):

I am also working on the same problem. I also have to deal with showing weather data to user using MVVM architecture. At the moment, I am stuck at the same point where you are right now. The solution seems to be something called 'Dependency Injection (DI)'. Basically, we can inject dependencies like `Context` to our `ViewModel` using tools/frameworks like 'Dagger 2'. DI has lower coupling than directly passing `Context` to `ViewModel` and results in better compliance with MVVM. So, the actual place of `FusedLocationProvider`, IMO, will be in ViewModel but after implementing DI. Maybe someone else can better elaborate on my explanation. I will update my answer once I implement Dependency Injection myself.

Comment: Sounds good. I have used the `ApplicationContext` with the `LocationManager` and injected the `LocationUtils`(class holding different methods to provide location-based feature) into `ViewModel`. Still looking for common and best practices.

Answer (score -1):

I put it in my ViewModel.
In order to pass `context` as an argument to your `ViewModel` you can extend `AndroidViewModel` instead of `ViewModel`. Example:

```
class CurrentViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    val context = application
    val locationResolver = LocationResolver(context)//this one converts latitude and longitude into City name of type String


fun detectCity() {
        Log.d(LocationResolver.TAG, "entered detectLocation()")
        val fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
            .addOnSuccessListener { location ->
                if (location != null) {
                    Repository._currentName.value = locationResolver.getLocationFromCoordinates(
                        location.latitude,
                        location.longitude
                    )
                    Log.d(
                        LocationResolver.TAG,
                        "New city name is:" + Repository.currentLocationCity
                    )
                }

            }
    }
```

Then you can observe the ouput via `DataBinding`.